# Gradle can't download artifacts from Fabric.io using https

Tags: android-gradle-plugin, twitter-fabric

The gradle script of my Android project stopped downloading artifacts from Fabric.io. I used the "-d" option to run the build script and I found that gradle had stucked in the SSL handshake:

```
13:36:54.459 [INFO] [org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec] Retrying request to {s}->https://fabric-artifacts.s3.amazonaws.com:443
13:36:54.459 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.client.protocol.RequestAddCookies] CookieSpec selected: default
13:36:54.459 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.client.protocol.RequestAuthCache] Auth cache not set in the context
13:36:54.459 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager] Connection request: [route: {s}->https://fabric-artifacts.s3.amazonaws.com:443][total kept alive: 1; route allocated: 0 of 2; total allocated: 1 of 20]
13:36:54.460 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager] Connection leased: [id: 2][route: {s}->https://fabric-artifacts.s3.amazonaws.com:443][total kept alive: 1; route allocated: 1 of 2; total allocated: 2 of 20]
13:36:54.460 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec] Opening connection {s}->https://fabric-artifacts.s3.amazonaws.com:443
13:36:54.584 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator] Connecting to fabric-artifacts.s3.amazonaws.com/54.231.49.202:443
13:36:54.968 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory] Connecting socket to fabric-artifacts.s3.amazonaws.com/54.231.49.202:443 with timeout 0
13:36:55.121 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory] Enabled protocols: [TLSv1, TLSv1.1, TLSv1.2]
13:36:55.121 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory] Enabled cipher suites:[TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV]
13:36:55.121 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory] Starting handshake
```

I could "fix" the problem changing the Fabric.io repository from https://maven.fabric.io/public to http://fabric-artifacts.s3.amazonaws.com/public. Any other https repository referenced by the project are working.

Is anyone facing the same issue?

Comment: Hi Eduardo! Todd from Fabric. Usually this is because of one of two issues, either you are behind a proxy or firewall or the dependencies on your machine have a mismatch. If you are behind a firewall please investigate. If you are not, please try running ./gradlew assemble --refresh-dependencies

Comment: Thanks Todd! The problem is probably the company's proxy. A guy from my team tried to run gradle with the "--refresh-dependencies" option. Regards.

Comment: To support a blocked traffic device, just whitelist the following domains on ports 80 and 443:

*.fabric.io
*.crashlytics.com

It's important to note that we don't support IP whitelisting because we use AWS and our IPs change very often. If you're using domains as a way of obtaining IP addresses, please be aware that the IP addresses will change very frequently - potentially every 24 hours.

Comment: Now gradle is working fine! Thanks for your help, Todd!